# putting source of all images into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the cleanest way to put the source attribute string of all images within a div into an array?

I was hoping this would work -

```
var imageSourceArray = $("#leDiv img").attr('src');
alert(imageSourceArray[3]);  //not alerting the source, boo hoo.
```

Do I need to loop through $("#leDiv img") and add each src string to an array individually? Or is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function which is described as:

> Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values.

For your example:

```
var mySources = $('#leDiv img').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('src');
}).get();
```

Comment: nice - not sure I fully understand it. *goes off to look at jquery docs*

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Far more elegant solution, there's obviously still some looping involved internally:

```
var img_sources = $('#leDiv img').map(function(){ return $(this).attr('src') });
```

---

You will in fact need to loop over the collection and add sources individually.

```
var img_sources = [];
$('#leDiv img').each(function(i,e){
    img_sources.push($(e).attr('src'))
})
```

---

Some background: `jQuery.fn.attr()` maps to `jQuery.access()` internally, the key part of which looks like this:

```
function( elems, key, value, exec, fn, pass ) {
    var length = elems.length;
    // setter functions omitted here …    

    // Getting an attribute
    return length ? fn( elems[0], key ) : undefined;
}
```

Note the `elems[0]` part – only the first item in the collection is fed to the subsequent callback function (`jQuery.attr()` in fact) responsible for extracting the information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was hoping there was a way to avoid the each statement. It looks like that's not possible. I'm going to leave the question open for a while more, just in case. I'm using your answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageSourceArray = [];
$('#leDiv img').each(function(){
   var src = $(this).attr("src");
   imageSourceArray.push(src);
});
alert(imageSourceArray[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you already have the src in a collection when you fetch the the images. It may be more efficient to not store the src attributes in another array:

```
$('#leDiv img').each(function(i,e){
    var dosomethingwith = $(e).attr('src');
})
```

or you could do:

```
var ImageCol = $('#leDiv img');
alert(ImageCol[3].attr('src'));
```